# Add Polyfill to craco, issue add a fallback 'resolve.fallback'

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, polyfills, craco

I'm getting an error:

> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
> - install 'path-browserify'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

Package.Json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
  //...
},
"scripts": {
  "contracts:compile:abi": "typechain --target ethers-v5 --out-dir src/abis/types \"./src/abis/**/*.json\"",
  "start": "craco start",
  "build": "craco build",
  "test": "craco test --coverage"
}
```

I don't have a `webpack.config`, and I'm not using `react-rewired-scripts` I think `Craco` does something similar but TBH I don't fully understand.

Here is my `craco.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  babel: {
    plugins: ['@vanilla-extract/babel-plugin'],
  },
  webpack: {
    plugins: [
      new VanillaExtractPlugin(),
      new DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.REACT_APP_GIT_COMMIT_HASH': JSON.stringify(commitHash.toString()),
      }),
    ],
    configure: (webpackConfig) => {
      const instanceOfMiniCssExtractPlugin = webpackConfig.plugins.find(
        (plugin) => plugin instanceof MiniCssExtractPlugin
      )
      if (instanceOfMiniCssExtractPlugin !== undefined) instanceOfMiniCssExtractPlugin.options.ignoreOrder = true
      return webpackConfig
    },
  },
}
```

How do I add a polyfill here?

Answer (score 2):

To solve this I added the fallback option in the configure method:

```
configure: (webpackConfig) => {

  webpackConfig.resolve.fallback = webpackConfig.resolve.fallback || {}
  webpackConfig.resolve.fallback.path = webpackConfig.resolve.fallback.path ?? require.resolve("path-browserify")

  //...
},
```